# Error deploying django website on docker through heroku - "Your app does not include a heroku.yml build manifest"

Tags: django, docker, heroku

I am in the final steps of deploying a django website. It uses docker to run it and I'm finally deploying it through heroku. I run into an error when running "git push heroku master". I receive "Your app does not include a heroku.yml build manifest. To deploy your app, either create a heroku.yml: [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml%22). This is odd as I do in fact have a heroku.yml app.

heroku.yml

```
setup:
    addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
    docker:
        web: Dockerfile
release:
    image: web
    command:
        - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
    web: gunicorn books.wsgi
```

The tutorial I am following is using "gunicorn bookstore_project.wsgi" but I used books.wsgi as that is the directory my website is in. Neither worked.

Comment: Are you certain that your `heroku.yml` file is commited and at the base of your repo?

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me when i pushed the wrong branch to heroku. I was testing in the develop branch but pushing master which had not `heroku.yml`.

pervious gitlab-ci

```yaml
stages:
  - staging

staging:
  stage: staging
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
    - git remote add heroku https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$PROJECT.git
    - git push -f heroku master
  only:
    - develop
```

actual gitlab-ci

```yaml
stages:
  - staging

staging:
  stage: staging
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
    - git remote add heroku https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$PROJECT.git
    - git push -f heroku develop:master
  only:
    - develop
```

Answer (score 0):

I was pushing from my local so I had to run the following:

```bash
git push heroku local-branch:main
```

Rename `local-branch` to your current branch.